# Drawing an oriented knot in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I drew this figure with the knot path effect in Inkscape.

[image]

Now I would like to add a few arrows. However, to apply the knot effect I had to make the entire figure into one path, so now when I add an arrow through "stroke style" I get this:

[image]

Is there a way to control these arrows? I would like arrows on some nodes only and the arrows on the two arcs from left to right to go in the same direction.

Comment: Just throwing out.. sometimes software won't, or can't do what you want in any sort of automated fashion. Not every feasible visual appearance is possible by selecting a few menu items or clicking a few buttons. Sometimes one must actually draw what they want to achieve. I'm not an Inkscape user, but in this instance, using the vector editor of my choice, I'd merely *draw* the arrows as I want them and not rely on software to place them precisely where I envision. Trying to achieve *everything* envisioned via menu commands is often a lesson in frustration using *any* software package.

Comment: I don't think the knot effect is designed to be used in combination with arrow markers. Maybe add the arrows manually.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess I should mark an arrow on a very short and thin line and position a copy of it manually over each of my arcs. Correct?

Comment: There's probably no *actual* need for any software-generated arrowhead... Simply create a *triangle* and place copies of that along the path at the angle and position you want.